# IntentService and AlarmManager communication

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Should alarm manager send PendingIntent to IntentService or is it better to send it to a broadcast receiver which then issues startService() targeting the pending intent?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That depends a bit on whether this is a `_WAKEUP` alarm or not.

If not, feel free to use a `getService()` `PendingIntent`.

If, however, it is a `_WAKEUP` alarm, not only do you need to use a `BroadcastReceiver` intermediary, but that `BroadcastReceiver` must also acquire a `WakeLock` which the `IntentService` later releases. The `BroadcastReceiver` requirement is due to the way `AlarmManager` handles its own `WakeLock`. I have wrapped all of this up as a [`WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) to simplify the implementation.