# Do I need to acquire a wakelock when not using a broadcast receiver to handle IntentServices sent from Alarm Manager?

Tags: android, intentservice, wakelock

I have been reading about starting a service from a BroadcastReceiver. In this scenario I have to acquire a WakeLock until the Intent is handled by the IntentService.

What about when I call an IntentService directly from the AlarmManager wrapped into a pendingIntent? In this scenario there's no BroadcastReceiver... the intent is forwarded directly to the onHandleIntent of the service. Then, where do I acquire the lock? Is it really needed??? All seems to work fine.

Comment: What would happen if the device went into sleep mode while you were processing the intent.  If nothing bad would happen, then no you don't need the lock.

Comment: Do you mean while the onHandleIntent method is being executed? So if I acquire the lock at the start of onHandleIntent and release it at the end, am I doing the correct thing?

Comment: Yes, that should prevent an interupption.

Comment: looks like based on this comment from @CommonsWare I am forced to use a BroadcastReceiver in the middle http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982920/intentservice-and-alarmmanager-communication

Comment: I'd have to look at his class, but I suppose that's the safest way.  It then handles the intent being queued and processed.  That way you don't miss an event and you're not interuppted while processsing it.

Comment: @HéctorJúdezSapena You should access the answer as it is the correct one. Otherwise please describe why you won't accept it.

Answer (score 1):

An `IntentService` is only a threaded service. You will need to aquire a wake lock. Commonsguy has a lovely `WakefulIntentService` [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful).

His IntentService acquires a Wakelock for you so if you call it from an AlarmService it will wake obtain the wake and release it when the work is done.

I've used it allot, works great, and the source is on Github so you can see how its working.

Comment: I've seen Commonsguy implementation but there's no BroadcastReceiver in my pattern. For what I understand, the lock is needed because once the onReceive method of the broadcast receiver finishes, there's a chance that the service may not start if the phone is sleeping. However, I am not using any broadcastreceiver at all... the AlarmManager has its own lock and it is the AlarmManager the one that starts the IntentService and not a broadcast receiver.

Comment: Yes but the alarmmanager will release ITS lock once it sends your Intent and the phone may power down while the intent is being processed

Comment: ok thanks, based on your comments and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982920/intentservice-and-alarmmanager-communication I am implementing the Alarm->Receiver->Service pattern using the lock system.

Comment: I assume the same thing has to be done if using classic services instead of IntentServices, am I right?

Comment: @HéctorJúdezSapena correct, An `IntentService` extends `Service` so as far as wake locks are concerned you need them for when ever you want your app to work when the device is asleep.

Comment: This is the correct answer. thanks @Chris.Jenkins for WakefulIntentService